# How to make the output stay on the screen for a period of time in Win32 app

Tags: c

I am trying to display the answer that is passed to the function til enter is pressed.The output is gone before i can see it.

```
 void answer(int p[][numCols],int count)
    {

      printf("\n");
      printf("Please press enter to end");


      printf("The answer is : %i",p[count][3]);
      char c=getchar();
      while (c != '\n')
      {
        c=getchar();

      }
    }
```

The code is available here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9419/programming-of-3-x-7-trick

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Ulimate 2010. Need some guidance how to solve it.

Comment: Are you saying that the output IS gone or that you want the output to be gone before you press enter.

Comment: i am saying the output is gone before i can see it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this function answer :

```
void answer(int p[][numCols],int count)
{
    char c;
    printf("\n");
    printf("Please press enter to end");
    printf("The answer is : %i",p[count][3]);
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        ;
}
```

And you can try another useful function named sleep();